# Ubuntu create user with password in GUI

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

Chen creating a new user in the Ubuntu GUI, it only asks for the users full name, username, and account type. It does not ask for a password.

But when I try to switch to the new user it asks for a password.

How do I set the password (in the GUI), or login as the new user?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to the "System Settings"
Select "User Accounts"
Create new user by clicking on the "+" button
Select "Account Type",enter Username and Full Name in the dialog box that appears.
Click "Add"

The **Solution**:
In the same window,on the right side,there is a Password field under **Login Options**.Click beside it (i.e. the password field),type in your desired password and Confirm it (by typing it again). And press **Enter**,or the **Change** button.

Comment: Thanks it was saying "Account Disabled", instead of "password" so I must have skimmed over it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the terminal like a boss.

> #### passwd username

[Enter New UNIX Password]

Comment: Tried that, it didn't work.